# Air for Android - System Settings

Tags: android, flash, air

Is it possible to adjust system's sound, brightness, turning on/off wifi and other settings in Air for android?

Please provide info or webpage links if you know any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in AIR, no. Most native capabilities are not available within an AIR app (which makes sense since AIR does not run natively)

But you could create an AIR Native Extension that would allow for it. I've never seen a pre-built one that can do it, so you would likely have to build it yourself.